# Hiding a div if a child element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Question correction:

I am trying to hide the entire 'li' block if the ptag inside of the 'li' is empty.

The p tag resides inside of the 'li' in a div with the class of
aaProfileDataWrapper

So if that p tag has no text inside of it then the entire 'li' need to hide including the labels and anything else it holds.

```js
var divs = $(".aaProfileDataWrapper");

divs.each(function () {
    var div = $(this);

    if (div.next().html() === "<p></p>") {
        div.hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="aaProfilePhone">
  <label>Office 2 Phone:</label> 
  <div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="aaInlineValidationWrapper">
    <div class="aaValidationWrapper-Inner">
      <span class="aaInlineValidationIcon"></span>
      <span class="aaValidationTxt"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML. Also *if a child class that holds a ptag* doesn't make any sense. A "class" cannot "hold" an element, nor can a "class" be a child.

Comment: div has a ID inside of that div is another div that has a class name and inside of that div is another div with a class name and that div holds the p tag.  Hence a id with a child and a ptag.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and add the relevant HTML along with a clarified explanation.

Comment: *There is a parent id for the div* <-- Not according to the code you've shared. Also, you are not using the `label` element correctly. it's meant to either wrap a form field or have the `for` attribute that has a value of an `id` of a form field. Since you are not using form fields, you should not be using `label`.

Comment: *and then a child class and then a p tag inside of that child* <-- Again, not according to the HTML you've shared. You describe a `div > some element with a class > p` structure, but what you've shown is `div > p`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus My apologies yes you are correct.  I meant to say everything was encased in an li not a parent.  This was my fault.  So to correct the above the code i posted is the code that is being used.  It is a li with div's inside of it.  I want to hide the entire li statement if the div with the class of aaProfileDataWrapper has nothing inside of the p tag.  Does this help?

Comment: @ScottMarcus  I edited my question and hopefully now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is query for al the `p` elements within any `div` element that has the `aaProfileDataWrapper` class that, themselves, are children of a `li` element. Then, you can loop over those `p` elements and, if they are empty, hide the `li` ancestor.

```js
// Loop over all the p elements within the div elements that
// have the right class, that are inside of li elements
$("li div.aaProfileDataWrapper p").each(function (idx, el) {
  // Check the p to see if it's empty
  if ($(el).html() === "") {
    $(el).closest("li").hide();  // Hide the nearest li ancestor
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="aaProfilePhone">
  <label>Office 1 Phone:</label> 
  <div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="aaInlineValidationWrapper">
    <div class="aaValidationWrapper-Inner">
      <span class="aaInlineValidationIcon"></span>
      <span class="aaValidationTxt"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li id="aaProfilePhone">
  <label>Office 2 Phone:</label> 
  <div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="aaInlineValidationWrapper">
    <div class="aaValidationWrapper-Inner">
      <span class="aaInlineValidationIcon"></span>
      <span class="aaValidationTxt"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for a `<p>` and then use `text().length` to see if it's empty.

```js
var divs = $(".aaProfileDataWrapper");

divs.each(function () {
  var p = $(this).find("p")
    if (!p.text().length > 0) {
        p.hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
<div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
<div class="aaProfileDataWrapper">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see how you could possibly answer this question since the question makes no sense.

Comment: `div.find('p').length` returns the number of `p` elements found within the `div` element, not whether those `p` elements are, themselves, empty.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Edited the answer :)

Comment: I still don't think we know enough about the problem to be able to answer.

Comment: @mylesthe.dev I have tried this and it does work and hides the ptag field which is great but I need to hide everything basically the entire li should be hidden if the ptag inside the li is empty.  I have tried to change your code from p.hide to li.hide and it hides the ptag field still but the label still shows up which means it is still only targeting the ptag.  To me this doesn't make sense because if I am telling it to hide the li  then it should all be hidden and not just the ptag.

Answer (score -1):

Plain old JavaScript to the rescue. Pleas let me know if there is any doubt.

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');

Array.from(divs).forEach((div) => {
  const p = div.querySelector('p');
  if (p && !p.innerText) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = null;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='some-class'>
  <p>Show</p>
</div>

<div class='some-class'>
  <p></p>
  Hide
</div>

<div class='some-class'>
  <p>Show</p>
</div>

<div class='some-class'>
  <p></p>
  Hide
</div>

<div class='some-class'>
  <p>Show</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see how you could possibly answer this question since the question makes no sense.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I assume by your reputation that you are well aware that the majority of the questions in Stack Overflow are poorly written. Everyone do their best to interpretate and elaborate an answer. It should be the OP to finally judge if that interpretation was accurate enough. When commenting an answer, you should only express your opinion about the answer itself, not the interpretation. Especially when the question is not 100% clear (if questions were not to be interpreted, this site would have little sense). I also assume that all the downvotes here are yours. You helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: You assume incorrectly. I didn't down vote anyone. I posted the comments because Stack Overflow is more than a place where a single person posts a question to get an answer. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base where others come to find answers to their problems as well. We want questions AND answers to be as clear and concise as possible. And so, we generally will wait until the question is clear before we post an answer.